# I am not able to Drag and Drop Entire folder with all its sub dirctory and files to the Browser container

Tags: javascript

I have requirement to drag and drop the entire folder including its sub-directory and files form local drive. Its working fine with google chrome. it supports html5. But when i am trying to do the same operation in IE 10 or Firefox...its not working !

Please give me any solution on this !

Comment: Its working in FF 28.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application internals were setting the following internally, and this was disabling drag-and-drop on IE10.

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9' />
```

?